# How to use regexp_substr() to return the numbers after a specific word in a string

Tags: regexp-substr

I have a table column full of strings like this:

'top-level:volume(1):semifinished(21491628):serial(21441769)'.

I would like to return just the numbers after 'serial' (i.e. '21441769') using regex_substr().

```
select ('top-level:volume(1):semifinished(21491628):serial(21441769)', ????)
```

Comment: What is your exact SQL database?

Comment: It is a snowflake database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` with a capture group:

```sql
SELECT col, REGEXP_SUBSTR(col, 'serial\\((\\d+)\\)', 1, 1, 'e', 1) AS serial
FROM yourTable;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this "(?<=serial().[0-9]+"

Comment: Thank you. I tried it and received this warning: "Invalid regular expression: '(?<=serial().[0-9]+', no argument for repetition operator: ?"

Comment: Weird I pasted it with this but it looks like it did not show up... You need to escape the ( with a backslash \